# Nice url with htaccess with specific parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have this form of URL : https://domain(:port)/lang/x/y/z/other

With this htaccess file, I can't achieve exactly what I want.

If I enter the URL https://localhost:port/lang/, I lose the port.
If I enter the URL https://localhost:port/lang, i got the URL https://localhost:port/langx/y/z

Please help me!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#LIVE
RewriteBase /

#--------------------------------------
#-- 404 & 500 Redirects
#--------------------------------------
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

#--------------------------------------
#-- Force HTTPS
#--------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=8088
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=8080
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^(actions)($|/) - [L]

#--------------------------------------
#-- Add trailing PHP and Params
#--------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5 [B,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [B,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [B,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#check for the existance of a PHP file first or else the 404 won't work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php?param1=$2 [B,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Consider using a simple `FallbackResource` and doing the routing in PHP. You will experience a performance boost. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: I just want to go with the current logic and add the lang as first param

Comment: check this link https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/ just add htaccess to folder